# Automatically add custom CSS to new posts using a category template

Tags: php, posts, templates

I have inherited the task of modifying a Wordpress site (using a child theme). I'm a designer, not a code or back-end expert.

I have been customizing a set of pages on a site to have alternative styling from the rest of the pages, using a plugin that allows custom CSS to be applied to individual pages. However, I need to get to a stage where this modifying CSS is automatically applied to new posts with a specific category, rather than the author having to do it.

I have worked out how to set up a category specific post template (having followed tutorials), but I have no idea how apply my custom CSS to this PHP template. I assume it doesn't just get added to the PHP template file (I tried that and the code appeared as text). Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have created a custom php template then add a specific class selector to your css within this template.  As an example:

```
<body class="mycustomclass">all your page content</body>
```

or

```
<content class="mycustomclass">all your content content</content>
```

It doesn't have to be on body or content or any other specific part of the page but make it encompass a the largest part of the content of that page.

Now in your child theme's style.css add the customization that you want:

```
.mycustomclass {
    color: blue
}

.mycustomclass h2 {
    font-size: 3rem;
}
```

This is a general answer but hopefully puts you in the right direction.

Comment: That is most helpful! I'll have a play around with that and see if I can get that to work.

Comment: OK, don't laugh. I have my CSS in place, but I'm not sure what to do with the .PHP template file. I tried the below, but it didn't work!

<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Cities Article
 * Template Post Type: post, page, product
 */

 get_header();  ?>

<body class="cities-class">all your page content</body>

<?php hu_get_content( 'tmpl/single-tmpl'); ?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>

Comment: You should look in your single-tmp.php file and look for the body div. Add "cities-class" to the classes already listed.  If that doesn't work, Post the content of your single-tmpl.php in your original question and then comment back so I get alerted.  I TRIED not to laugh!! :)